# Powershell find webserver certificate expiration with context in URL

Tags: powershell, certificate

need help with Powershell.
We need to find server certificate expiration using powershell. These are weblogic console Urls. The URLs have context and port like https://server:7020/context .  If I browse URL without context, I get error -

```
Error 404--Not Found
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.4.5 404 Not Found
```

I have tried with following code -

```
Try{
$Conn = New-Object 

System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($WebsiteURL,$WebsitePort)

Try {
$Stream = New-Object 

System.Net.Security.SslStream($Conn.GetStream(),$false, {

param($sender, $certificate, $chain, $sslPolicyErrors)
return $true
})
$Stream.AuthenticateAsClient($CommonName)
```

If I try a server without context it gives following error -

```
A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
```

What are commands and options to query in powershell?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The path stem ("context") won't have any bearing on the certificate being presented, so you only need to worry about changing the port - maybe show us an example of what you've tried/failed to do?

Comment: Updated the original post. When tried on browser, do not see a response without a context. Using powershell get above error.

Comment: The error is caused by mismatching TLS versions. Presumably, your server is using TLS 1.2 - set your PS session to match at the start of your script with `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Comment: Thanks CrookedJ.. The issue was with TLS 1.2. Need to update the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Get-RemoteSslCertificate` [from jstangroome](https://gist.github.com/jstangroome/5945820) you can simply run the following to return the expiration.

```
(Get-RemoteSslCertificate -ComputerName server -Port 7020).NotAfter
```

The `Get-RemoteSslCertificate` function:

```
function Get-RemoteSslCertificate {
    # Author: jstangroome https://gist.github.com/jstangroome/5945820
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $ComputerName,
    
        [int]
        $Port = 443
    )
    
    $Certificate = $null
    $TcpClient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
    try {
    
        $TcpClient.Connect($ComputerName, $Port)
        $TcpStream = $TcpClient.GetStream()
    
        $Callback = { param($sender, $cert, $chain, $errors) return $true }
    
        $SslStream = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Security.SslStream -ArgumentList @($TcpStream, $true, $Callback)
        try {
    
            $SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient('')
            $Certificate = $SslStream.RemoteCertificate
    
        } finally {
            $SslStream.Dispose()
        }
    
    } finally {
        $TcpClient.Dispose()
    }
    
    if ($Certificate) {
        if ($Certificate -isnot [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]) {
            $Certificate = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 -ArgumentList $Certificate
        }
    
        Write-Output $Certificate
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks good. But does not help if we have to context.

Comment: That's not how HTTPS works, `context` is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks CrookedJ.. The issue was with TLS 1.2. Need to update the script.